# How can I fix the "undefined class constant 'insecure_extension_regex' in {closure}()" error?

Tags: upgrading

I'm upgrading some Drupal 8.9 modules and it gave me this error.

> undefined class constant 'insecure_extension_regex' in {closure}()

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

Does anyone know how to fix it?

The only thing I found was to replace line 32 of file.post_update.php, but it still gives me an error.

Answer (score 1):

The code shown in the third screenshot is part of [`file_post_update_add_txt_if_allows_insecure_extensions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.post_update.php/function/file_post_update_add_txt_if_allows_insecure_extensions/9.3.x), a post-update hook introduced in Drupal 9.2.

```php
// Determine if this field uses an item definition that extends FileItem.
if (is_subclass_of($field->getItemDefinition()->getClass(), FileItem::class)) {
  $allowed_extensions_string = trim($field->getSetting('file_extensions'));
  $allowed_extensions = array_filter(explode(' ', $allowed_extensions_string));
  if (in_array('txt', $allowed_extensions, TRUE)) {
    // Since .txt is specifically allowed, there's nothing to do.
    return FALSE;
  }
  foreach ($allowed_extensions as $extension) {
    // Allow .txt if an insecure extension is allowed.
    if (preg_match(FileSystemInterface::INSECURE_EXTENSION_REGEX, 'test.' . $extension)) {
      $allowed_extensions_string .= ' txt';
      $field->setSetting('file_extensions', $allowed_extensions_string);
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

The [`FileSystemInterface::INSECURE_EXTENSION_REGEX`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21FileSystemInterface.php/constant/FileSystemInterface%3A%3AINSECURE_EXTENSION_REGEX/9.3.x) constant has been defined since Drupal 9.2.

I take the site doesn't have the *core/lib/Drupal/Core/File/FileSystemInterface.php* file that comes with Drupal 9, but it still has the file that comes with Drupal 8. It could also be that file is corrupted, and PHP doesn't find that constant.

Comment: Thanks a lot by your comments.
 I have been trying to update my site to D9 for several months and I always get a new error and again and again. Also the theme I use was not migrated to D9 and that is a big problem I have. I'm going to try to rebuild my site from scratch with D9 and then migrate the content. It's a long way but I've been doing that since D6.

Comment: Since it's possible to migrate content from a Drupal 8 site to a Drupal 9 site, that's probably the solution that works better, especially when you keep getting errors when you try to upgrade.